# FarCry CMS search results not found

Tags: lucee, commandbox

I have recently installed [FarCry CMS](https://www.farcrycore.org/) 7.2.8 with Chelsea Boots via [Commandbox](https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/embedded-server). The menu links work without any problem except the search field, where i get 404 error for every input parameter.

[image]

I have configured Commandbox (.htaccess) [rewrite rules](https://www.ortussolutions.com/blog/the-12-tips-of-commandbox-christmas-day-10-converting-apache-and-iis-url-rewrites) via [FarCry friendly urls](https://farcry.jira.com/wiki/spaces/FCDEV50/pages/3440768/Friendly+URLs) for Apache configuration, but i have still got the same error.

[image]

Any idea that could help me?

Regards

Comment: Can you please post the [code you already have](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of any specific code that causes this kind of problem. I think that the only way to reproduce is to download and install it via commandbox the way I mention it. Regards

Comment: Then maybe this is the wrong place - does FarCry CMS have some kind of technical support?

Comment: I have already done it and there is no response at the moment. (https://github.com/farcrycore/core/issues/102 and https://discourse.farcrycore.org/t/search-friendly-url-issue/1698/8). If anyone could help me, I would be delighted. Regards